# What library is used for the main menu in the facebook iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, menu

I'm making an app that has more options than will easily fit into a UITabBarController. I wanted to use something like what the facebook app has for its main menu.

[image: facebook main menu]

My guess is that it isn't proprietary to facebook, because the SCVNGR app uses something similar.

[image: SCVNGR main menu]

This library lets you re-order the icons the way you can re-order the apps from the main menu (i.e. press and hold -> icons jiggle -> you can drag them around).

Does anyone know what library provides this UIView? I'd like to use it if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the [Three20](http://three20.info/) framework; specifically it's the [launcher](http://three20.info/showcase/launcher) feature.

Answer (score 1):

three20 is what you're looking for.

http://three20.info/